# Where do Meggie and Mo (and Elinor) live originally?

Tags: real-location, inkheart-trilogy

The novel *Inkheart* begins in the home of Meggie and Mo(rtimer) Folchart, and within a few chapters they go to visit Aunt Elinor's house where a lot of later scenes in the first two books take place.

**Where are these locations?** Do we have enough info from the story to at least pin down a country? Of course the book was originally written in German, but are Mo and Meggie Germans originally living in Germany? Or are the real-world locations left deliberately vague to defy identification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the locations are deliberately left vague. In *Inkheart* Mo and his wife are said to have relatives scattered all over Europe:

> Mo had already taken her to visit various relations. Both he and
> Meggie’s mother had large families whose homes, so far as Meggie could
> see, were scattered over half of Europe.

which is highly non-specific! However, Elinor is specifically stated to live in northern Italy:

> Your mother has an aunt called Elinor. We visited her once, when you
> were very small... She lives beside a lake in the north of Italy

In an question and answer thread on Goodreads, Funke remarked that the [Inkbooks are set in Liguria](https://www.goodreads.com/questions/622426-hello-i-m-italian-and-i-really-love-the). In *Inkheart*, Dustfinger states that Capricorn's village is 300 km south of Elinor's home:

> ‘There,’ he said. ‘Capricorn’s village is just there.’ Elinor looked
> over his shoulder. ‘Liguria,’ she said.

which would put Elinor's house near the Italian-Swiss border.

Mo and Meggie (and Dustfinger) travelled to Elinor's place in a van. The trip began in mid-morning and ended at twilight, so took approximately ten hours or so (depending on the time of year - on the day they left, the sun had already risen by 5 am, which would seem to indicate summer.) They travelled south, passing through mountains, and at least nine tunnels before Meggie fell asleep. That is certainly compatible with them living in southern Germany and passing through the Alps on the way to Italy. Frankfurt to Genoa by car, for example, is a southern trip which takes about 9 hours. Switzerland would seem to be too close for the trip to last this long.

Comment: Great info and investigation. Could you add specific quotes/sources for the bit about northern Italy and Liguria (and for that matter the "half of Europe" quote)?